# NoReverseMatch on a complicated parameter URL

Tags: django

I have a named url called "my_url": *(urls.py)*

```
url(r'^a/(?P<var1>\w+)/b/(?P<var2>\w+)$', views.my_view, name="my_url")
```

I try to redirect to it, but I can't match.

```
return redirect(reverse("my_url", kwargs={"var1":something, "var2":something_else}))
```

Is it because of the 'a' and 'b' characters? How can I correctly call `redirect` on it? Here's the `NoReverseMatch` error:

```
1 pattern(s) tried: ['a/(?P<var1>\\w+)/b/(?P<var2>\\w+)$']
```

Comment: What are `something` and `something_else`? You specify `\w+` in url pattern which means alphanumeric, so anything else wouldn't fit in.

Comment: In this case, `something` is a crc32 hash, and `something_else` is a urlencoded email address (but I'm just testing it with an [a-z] string for the moment, so I believe it should work.

Comment: Please post the whole error trace back.

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot. You're right, the `%40` was killing the regex! I'll delete this question.

Comment: I think it's somewhat useful to keep the question. People often fall into the trap of the regex, but it's up to you.

Comment: Don't delete the question. Even when this error never happened to me, I find this clarification pretty useful since most of the times we use \w+ for simplicity expecting that pattern is an Ash-Ketchum-like pattern which catches 'em all, but it is not the case for special characters. +1q +1a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, on Shang's suggestion, I'll post his answer: My `var2` was intended to contain an email address, which contains characters prohibited by the `\w+` in the regex. This therefore didn't match the url pattern, and hence the `NoReverseMatch` error.